# Script execution in unity's scene mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've followed [a](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgcHw8b81SE) YouTube Tutorial for Unity 3D.

*Everything* is working so far when using the **Game** mode. But when I preview the **Scene** mode it seems my scripts are not executed - but in the YouTube tutorial the changes are already visible in the **Scene** mode.

**How do I let execute scripts in the Scene mode??**

Comment: After you hit the play button, switching to the scene mode doesn't show any changes, is that correct? Please post some code that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: No, it's not correct actually. I save the .cs in monodevelop, switch to Unity and nothing happens. In the video it gets shown in the scene mode. I know that unity execute the script when I save it. At least it tries to compile it, since I get the errors when there are some. But currently there are no errors.

Comment: At what time in the video does this happen? In all instances I've seen, he pretty clearly clicks the play button and then pauses before anything is visible in the scene mode due to a script update.

Comment: I get it. Didn't recognized this. In my (default) configuration it instantly switches to the **Game** mode when I press play. Well, that's the answer to my question actually - feel free to post it. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make your script execute in edit mode, just use [ExecuteInEditMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) custom attribute:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    void Update() {
        if (target)
            transform.LookAt(target);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only see the result of script actions in the scene mode once the scene is running (through pressing play). Once running, you can switch to scene mode and see things happen in realtime, as well as being able to pause, resume or switch back to "game" mode.

Comment: Note that this answer isn't exactly correct, look at the answer below by @giacomelli

Comment: Very interesting, and I didn't know this was possible. thanks!